# Running Linux in text mode - blank diamonds instead of Chinese/Punjabi etc. characters

Tags: terminal, console, unicode, text, i18n

While in the text mode and using, for example, **Chinese/Simplified** or **India/Punjabi** locale I get blank diamond symbols in the console in place of the characters.

I am running Xubuntu with

```
language-pack-pa*
language-pack-zh*
```

installed.

When I change the locale to, say, Russian it works as expected:

```
johnny@xubuntu:~$ cat /etc/default/locale.ruru
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="ru_RU:ru"
johnny@xubuntu:~$ sudo cp /etc/default/locale.ruru /etc/default/locale
...
johnny@xubuntu:~$ date
Ср. янв. 14 13:26:18 GMT 2015          // <-----
```

When I change to, say, Chinese I get diamonds:

```
johnny@xubuntu:~$ cat /etc/default/locale.zhcn
LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="zh_CN:zh"
johnny@xubuntu:~$ sudo cp /etc/default/locale.zhcn /etc/default/locale
...
johnny@xubuntu:~$ date
2015◆ 01◆ 14◆ ◆◆◆ 13:27:26 GMT         // <-----
```

If I then start X session everything works fine, script is displayed correctly in the terminal and so are the labels on GUI elements.

How to fix it in the console?

Comment: I guess this has something to do with a font. In text mode different fonts are used than in X. Doing a simple googling says that it might be not possible to achieve in text mode https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=83350 and http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.1/chapter07/console.html

Comment: I was thinking that too but installing whatever Punjabi fonts I could find didn't help. Thanks for the links. In the first one someone mentioned [fbterm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fbterm) replacement for kernel terminal and the initial results are very promising!

Comment: I post it as an answer then

Answer (score 2):

I guess this has something to do with a font. In text mode different fonts are used than in X. Doing a simple googling says that it might be not possible to achieve in text mode [Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=83350) and [LFS Console](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.1/chapter07/console.html)